# How to resume a previous incomplete job in apache nutch crawler

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch, resume

I am using nutch 2.3. There is a possible chance that during any stage of nutch (fetch parse index etc.), network probelm occur or power shutdown happen. How I can resume previous incomplete job.

Please give some example for explaination?

Answer (score 2):

There a `-resume` parameter for these commands, it doesn't work?
http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20fetch

Comment: I tried but that does not work although with -resume script run successfully but if crawler was stopped at fetching etc. then I expect it should resume from that point but with -resume, job is finished even less than a minute. I think that less information about -reume may be the issue